# Deriving the marginal likelihood of a Gaussian Process

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, gaussian-process

I've seen some questions and answers here that don't really do it for me.

I'm looking at p19 of Rasmussen and Williams.

We have that the marginal likelihood is:

$$ p(y|X) = \int p(y|f,X)p(f|X)df $$

$$ p(f|X) \sim N(0,K) $$
$$ p(y|f,X) \sim N(f,\sigma^2I) $$

Therefore we have:
$$ p(y|X) = \int N(f,\sigma^2I)N(0,K)  $$

The product of two Gaussians is:
$$ N(f,\sigma^2I)N(0,K)=Z^{-1}N(x|c,C) $$

where $ c = C(A^{-1}a+B^{-1}b) $ and $ C = (A^{-1}+B^{-1})^{-1}$

I've got $Z^{-1} $ as

$$ Z^{-1} = (2\pi)^{d/2}\times|K+\sigma^2I|^{-1/2}\times exp(\frac{-1}{2}\times(-f)^{T}\times(K+\sigma^2I)^{-1}\times(-f)) $$

**This is where I think I'm coming unstuck;**

substituting in our values for the variance:

$$ C = (K^{-1} + (\sigma^2I)^{-1})^{-1} $$
$$ \implies C = (K^{-1} + (\sigma^2I))^{-1} $$

and the mean:
$$ c = (K^{-1} + (\sigma^2I))^{-1}\times(\sigma^2If)  $$

Given that I'm supposed to find that $ y \sim N(0,K+\sigma^2I) $ I'm pretty sure I've made a mistake.

I'll admit my matrix algebra is little shaky; the variance looks like it might be on the right track but I'm really stuck. I've been trying all day to get it...

Can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use the formulas for the pdf of a multivariate normal distribution.  In exponentials, you will obtain a quadratic form of $\boldsymbol{f}$ as well as a linear term of $\boldsymbol{f}$; therefore, the integral can be represented as an expectation of the exponential of a linear term of $\boldsymbol{f}$, which equals the MGF.  Use this result to simplify

Comment: You will also have to use the Woodbury matrix identity to simplify

Comment: To whoever is down-voting this question: please explain why

Comment: Note that in your final expression for $c$ you have $f$... But $f$ is what you're integrating out.  I'd suggest working through the product if two normals again, then arrange terms.in the exponential term to make $f$ easy to integrate out, and on from there.

Comment: @jbowman are you saying that I should substitute in c and C and start rearranging inside the exp? Have I even got c and C correct? (I don't think that my inverse simplification is correct) i.e. I shouldn't drop the inverse from the Identity matrix inside of the brackets

Comment: Just ignore everything not in the exponential terms, they are all constant of integration stuff.  You then have two quadratics, both involving $f$.  Rearranging terms between them makes the variance clear and allows you to separate it into a quadratic with only $y$ and one with only $f$.  If you think carefully, you'll realize that since all you care about are terms involving $y$, you don't even have to do the integration and can just ignore the $f$ terms.  The functional form will reveal what the posterior parameters are quite easily.

Comment: @RNs_Ghost what are $a,b,A,B$?.  The formula you are using is presented poorly

Comment: @jbowman How do you factor out the cross-term $\boldsymbol{f}^{\prime}\boldsymbol{y}$?

Comment: There is a trick involving adding and subtracting $\bar{y}$ ... I am in phone only territory, so not able to help as much as your question deserves.